# How to Split One Column into Multiple Columns in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column "match" in my dataframe and I'd like to split in two columns called "home" and "away", but I get an error.

This is my column "match":

[image]

and I'd like to use seperator "-" to split it.

This is my specific part of code:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
df = pd.DataFrame(_get_rows(matchlink)).set_index("match")
df[['Home','Away']] = df['match'].str.split(" - ",expand=True) 
df[['HomeScore','AwayScore']] = df['result'].str.split(":",expand=True) 
df = df.sort_values('odds1')

print(df)
```

And this is my full code:

```
from typing import Generator

from requests_html import HTMLSession
import pandas as pd

matchlink = "https://www.betexplorer.com/football/serbia/prva-liga/results/"


def _get_rows(url: str) -> Generator[dict[str, str], None, None]:
session = HTMLSession()

r = session.get(matchlink)

allmatch = r.html.find(".in-match")
results = r.html.find(".h-text-center a")
# search for elements containing "data-odd" attribute
matchodds = r.html.find("[data-odd]")

odds = [matchodd.attrs["data-odd"] for matchodd in matchodds]

idx = 0
for match, res in zip(allmatch, results):
    if res.text == "POSTP.":
        continue

    print(f"{match.text} Z {res.text} {', '.join(odds[idx:idx+3])}")
    yield {
        "match": match.text,
        "result": res.text,
        "odds": ", ".join(odds[idx : idx + 3]),
        "odds1": (odds[idx]), "odds2": (odds[idx+1]), "odds3": (odds[idx+2]),
    }

    idx += 3


if __name__ == "__main__":
df = pd.DataFrame(_get_rows(matchlink)).set_index("match")
df.to_dict('tight')
df[['Home','Away']] = df['match'].str.split(" - ",expand=True) 
df[['HomeScore','AwayScore']] = df['result'].str.split(":",expand=True) 
df = df.sort_values('odds1')

print(df)


# determining the name of the file
file_name = 'MarksData.xlsx'

# saving the excel
df.to_excel(file_name)
print('DataFrame is written to Excel File successfully.')
```

I'd like to say that the follow line works:

> df[['HomeScore','AwayScore']] = df['result'].str.split(":",expand=True)

but this similar line doesn't work:

> df[['Home','Away']] = df['match'].str.split(" - ",expand=True)

Thanks

**EDIT** This is my output error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\OSTI\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 3790, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "index.pyx", line 152, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "index.pyx", line 181, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 7080, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 7088, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: 'match'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\OSTI\programmazione\python\livescores\allresults_test.py", line 40, in <module>
    df[['Home','Away']] = df['match'].str.split(" ",expand=True)
                          ~~^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\OSTI\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3893, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\OSTI\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 3797, in get_loc
    raise KeyError(key) from err
KeyError: 'match'
```

Comment: can you provide the output of `df.to_dict('tight')` right after `pd.DataFrame(_get_rows(matchlink)).set_index("match")`? It's a better [mre] than having to run the full code

Comment: @mozway I am a newbie of Python and I don't know if I undestood well your question, but I edited my post. Thanks

Comment: @Terra1 What mozway is saying is to provide `print(df.to_dict('tight'))`. When your code (`df[['Home','Away']] = df['match'].str.split(" - ",expand=True)`) is working, **df doesn't have match column.** Instead of uploading the entire code, you should isolate the problem by checking at each step which object you are using and which function you are using.

Comment: No that's not what I meant. Please run `print(pd.DataFrame(_get_rows(matchlink)).set_index("match").to_dict('tight'))` and provide the output as addendum. If you have many rows, just `print(pd.DataFrame(_get_rows(matchlink)).set_index("match").head(10).to_dict('tight'))`

Comment: @Terra1 Anyway, this problem occurs because you used `set_index` function on `df` to make match column the index, **so df does not have match column** and therefore an error occurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you don't have a column named `'match'`. The `'match'` is your index. So you need to reset the index before splitting, or don't set it as your index to begin with.

so change `df = pd.DataFrame(_get_rows(matchlink)).set_index("match")` to `df = pd.DataFrame(_get_rows(matchlink))`

OR

```
df = df.reset_index(drop=False)  # <-- Add this line before the split()
df[['Home','Away']] = df['match'].str.split(" - ",expand=True)
```